# React Native : Cannot read property 'Document Dir' of undefined when importing react-native-fetch-blob

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I was trying to use react-native-fetch-blob in my project, but whenever I put an

`import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'`

and I get an error on the emulator as

`Cannot read property 'Document Dir' of undefined`

I have installed it using

```
npm i --save react-native-fetch-blob
```

and linked it using

```
react-native link
```

Error :

> Cannot read property 'DocumentDir' of undefined 
>       fs.js:24:31 loadModuleImplementation
>       require.js:214:4 guardedLoadModule
>       require.js:148:11
>   _require
>       require.js:132:2 
>       index.js:21 loadModuleImplementation
>       require.js:214:4 guardedLoadModule
>       require.js:148:11
>   _require
>       require.js:132:2 
>       App.js:6 loadModuleImplementation
>       require.js:214:4

Comment: Hopefully this can help: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/251

Comment: I have the same issue, did you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing and linking the package. Do the following

```
watchman watch-del-all

npm cache clean --force
```

`rm -f /ios/build` (if you are building for ios)
`rm -f /android/build` (if you are building for android)

```
react-native run-ios `or` react-native run-ios
```

Hope it solves your problem